# Single link clustering

Tags: python, opencv, cluster-analysis

I'm looking for a way to do single link clustering with OpenCV.  My scenario:

- Hundreds (potentially thousands) of feature vectors (vectors dimension can be up to ~800 features).
- Unknown number of clusters (likely to be much lower than the number of vectors).
- Fixed similarity threshold `E` - if the l1 norm between two vectors is less than `E`, then the vectors should be in the same cluster.
- I don't need a cluster to be compact.  That is, I don't need all the vectors in the cluster to be within `E` of each other.  This can lead to long "chains" instead of clusters, but I'm OK with this.

I tried using K-means, but because I don't know the number of clusters it's not really applicable here.  I could do iterative K-means and look for the best K, but it sounds inefficient.  Is there a more suitable clustering algorithm implemented in OpenCV that I could use here?

Ideally, I need something similar to the [SLINK algorithm](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~wkim/index_files/papers/sibson.pdf), as this is what is quoted in the paper that I'm currently trying to implement.  My options are to implement SLINK directly (a bit of a task, because of debugging & testing) or look for an existing algorithm that does something similar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing an implementation by myself:

```
import cv
def main():
    import sys
    x = cv.Load(sys.argv[1])
    epsilon = float(sys.argv[2])
    y = cv.CloneImage(x)
    labels = range(x.height)
    tmp = cv.CreateImage((x.width, 1), x.depth, x.nChannels)
    for i in range(x.height):
        cv.SetImageROI(x, (0, i, x.width, 1))
        for j in range(i+1, x.height):
            cv.SetImageROI(y, (0, j, x.width, 1))
            cv.AbsDiff(x, y, tmp)
            dist, _, _, _ = cv.Avg(tmp)
            if dist < epsilon:
                for k, lbl in enumerate(labels):
                    if lbl == j:
                        labels[k] = i

    for i, lbl in enumerate(labels):
        print i, lbl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`x` is a `N x M` matrix containing `N` vectors.  The dimensionality of a vector is `M`.  It basically compares each pair of vectors using the L1 norm, and considers a pair to be identical if their difference is less than `epsilon`.  This algorithm is very slow --- `O(N^3)`, but it's good enough for me at the moment.

Comment: The key difference between `SLINK` and the naive hierarchical clustering is the speedup. IIRC, `SLINK` is `O(n^2)`. You might want to have a look on how this is achieved.
Nevertheless, hierarchical clustering is and ages old and pretty naive technique. It does not cope well with noise. You might want to try `DBSCAN` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I read the SLINK paper.  As you mention, the speed-up is one advantage.  The other one is you don't need to store the entire connectivity matrix in memory (you can pass values in one-by-one, provided its in a special arrangement).  I actually ended up doing what @Avaris suggested in the end.  It works well enough.  I'll have a look at DBSCAN if I ever return to this problem again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest constructing a graph by your similarity threshold and finding [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29). Once you construct the graph, finding connected components will be fairly easy and efficient. If you like [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) already has a connected component [function](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.number_connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.number_connected_components).